How to Evaluate a Model in a Train Size Ablation Study with Small Datasets?
I’m working on a supervised classification model with a small dataset (~200 samples). My goal is to create a model that performs well with as few training samples as possible. To test this, I’m planning an ablation study where I systematically reduce the training size (e.g., 20, 40, 60 samples, etc.) and evaluate the model’s performance.
I’m unsure about the best way to evaluate the model in this context. Should I use k-fold-cross-validation? If so, how should I handle the number of folds? For example, if the training size is very small, should I reduce the number of folds to avoid overly small validation sets?
Additionally, does the fact that the validation size changes between different training sizes affect the results? Should I try to normalize or control for this?
Are there any alternative approaches or best practices for conducting this type of study? I’ve tried simple train-test splits, but with a small dataset, the results can vary a lot depending on the split.
I’d appreciate any advice on how to ensure reliable and fair evaluation for this kind of ablation study.
